# @JsonbTypeDeserializer and @JsonbTypeSerializer don't work in the fields

Tags: java, json-deserialization, jsonb, jsonbuilder

I'm in an activity of exchanging **Jackson** for **Jsob-B** and I am having a problem on use **@JsonbTypeDeserializer** and **@JsonbTypeSerializer** as told below.

I have an entity like this:

```
 public class User implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private String login;

  @JsonbTypeDeserializer(Decrypting.class)
  @JsonbTypeSerializer(Encrypting.class)
  private String password;

  // getters and setter
}
```

And one test like this:

```
  @Test
  public void whenDeserializingUsingJsonbTypeDeserializer() throws IOException {

    String json = "{\"login\":\"admin\", \"password\":\"yfv_ntl3_Nbrv0139tDwRQ\"}";

    Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();

    User user = jsonb.fromJson(json, User.class);

    Assert.assertEquals(user.getPassword(), "test-string");
  }
```

When running the test, the Decryption class is trying to deserialize the **login** field, but, as you can see, only the **password** field has annotations.

Any way to fix it?

Comment: any runtime ? spring boot ? thorntail ? ....

Comment: We use zulu jdk 8

Comment: `the deserializer is trying to deserialize the login field` sounds logic... you mean that it use your custom deserializer for login too ?

Comment: What I meant is that I don't want the Decrypting class to be used to deserialize the login field, this is what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

After update for new versions, I had a problem with **JsonbConfigProperties.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES** that I switched for **YassonConfig.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES** and now everything works fine.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.json.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.json.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```